# Vb6 Missing Operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb6

Working on my school project and am coming across this missing operator error when i added in the `ORDER BY` aspect to my sql despite the rest of the code running fine.

```
Set rs_fav = db_kwickfix.OpenRecordset("
    SELECT Recipe.Rec_Name 
    FROM Recipe,Favourites 
    WHERE (Recipe.RecipeID = Favourites.RecipeID) 
        AND (Favourites.UserID = " & frm_login.user_id & ") 
    ORDER BY Recipe.Rec_Name DESCENDING
    ")
```

Comment: Perhaps try changing your inner double quotes to single quotes ( the ones around frm_login.user_id)

Comment: I added the `SQL-Server` tag, feel free to remove it if you're using another DBMS ;)

Comment: Smells like DAO, so most likely not SQL Server but Jet.

Answer (score 4):

Try **`DESC`** and not **`DESCENDING`**, check [ORDER BY Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188385.aspx) which is:

> ORDER BY order_by_expression
>   [ COLLATE collation_name ]
>   [ ASC | DESC ]
>   [ ,...n ]
>   [ <offset_fetch> ]

Thus:

```
Set rs_fav = db_kwickfix.OpenRecordset("
    SELECT Recipe.Rec_Name 
    FROM Recipe,Favourites 
    WHERE (Recipe.RecipeID = Favourites.RecipeID) 
        AND (Favourites.UserID = " & frm_login.user_id & ") 
    ORDER BY Recipe.Rec_Name DESC
    ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using an explicit JOIN?

```
Set rs_fav = db_kwickfix.OpenRecordset("
        SELECT Recipe.Rec_Name 
        FROM Recipe
        JOIN Favourites
        ON Recipe.RecipeID = Favourites.RecipeID
        AND Favourites.UserID = " & frm_login.user_id & " 
        ORDER BY Recipe.Rec_Name DESC
    ")
```

Also, I highly recommend looking into parameterized queries so that you can start getting into a habit of using them. Read more about it [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlphp/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries/).

Comment: Here the Join is useless, apart for improving readability. The query engine will produce the same code with `WHERE` or `JOIN`

Comment: Aren't you also reducing the likelihood of an unwanted cross join by making the JOIN explicit? I can see what you're saying though - it won't solve his particular issue.

Comment: Good question... you should use `CROSS JOIN table` to make an explicit one, and the implicit way is to forgot the full `WHERE table1.field = table2.field`, this can happen, but I don't think it's a real risk... (but don't think I'm against the `JOIN` syntax, I always use it, the `WHERE` one is more for legacy code)